Can a Schengen country issue a national non-Schengen visa?
Do members of Schengen always issue Schengen visas, which enable the person to travel within Schengen or can a member state issue a non Schengen visa or apply limitations to a Schengen visa?
For example: in my country there is a big problem of people coming in with a short stay visa C, for example as tourists or seasonal workers, then they cross the border into another Schengen country and apply for a job there.
Can some visas be limited to one country or do Schengen members always issue Schengen visas, wether they want to or not?
I know that entry into Schengen can be refused, despite a Schengen visa, for example if the visa is based on facts, which are not credible or if accommodation is missing and such.
But how does it work for travelling between Schengen countries, do the same rules apply?
For entrepreneurs working in the tourism industry it is a very confusing situation, because their guest workers get issued Schengen visas, but if the worker uses the Schengen visa to go to another country the company may get investigated for human trafficking, according to politicians I spoke to. Often buying the worker tickets back to their country of origin is not enough to deter them. But I wonder if there is any legal basis to prevent them from travelling with their Schengen visas and why this responsibility is on the hotel and not on the government which gave them a Schengen visa, they ultimately don't want them to use.

You seem to be asking several different things. Most EU countries will issue long-term residency permits and other documents as well as Schengen visas. And EU freedom of movement generally means you can move and work, but there are limits (Denmark seems to have its own rules). But I'm not sure why you're talking about human trafficking and preventing people travelling: it sounds like you're wanting to bring workers into the country and then force them to stay working with you, which is as I understand it illegal as well as off-topic.

In most (?) cases nothing is checked when you travel between countries that are part of the Schengen area. as the authorities assume that if you were allowed to be in one country that is a member, you're allowed to be in all countries that are members. If a country started letting people in that are only allowed in their country, the other countries would have to check everyone arriving from that country, which would effectively be like the first country not being a member at all.

@StuartF I do not want to force people to stay, the government is trying to prevent it from happening (people moving freely). And they say if your workers go to another country, that makes you a human trafficker. It is very confusing situation.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity in theory there are no checks, but in practice there are. For example last time I went to Vienna, there was police checking passports in the plane tunnel thing. And I think even if you have a schengen visa they can decline entry on some grounds.

@user1721135 They are clearly allowed to go to another Schengen country, that is most definitely not the issue. The issue is that they either work illegally or overstay, most probably both.

@jcaron I have never seen or heard about illegal work in EU in the last 5-10 years. It is simply too easy to get a work permit. What is happening is they go to another country and apply for a work permit, which gives them the right to stay until a decision is made, after that they get a brand new visa. I don't think its illegal to be honest, it seems like bulgaria simply trying to make austria happy to remove the veto.

@user1721135 We must not live in the same EU. Of course there are tons of people working without a permit or even staying without a visa. And again, work permits are national, not Schengen-wide. It may be easy in your country, it's not the case in many other Schengen countries.

@jcaron I know lots of foreigners in many countries, I have not heard of illegal work for a very long time. Illegal overtime and stuff like that sure, but completely illegal no. That is because there aren't many visa options for staying long term but not being allowed to work. And staying without visa and without legal work is impossible for non refugees.

@user1721135 Illegal, sure. Impossible, most definitely not. Once they're in, they're very difficult to find and send back. And many probably file for asylum even if completely inapplicable to them, just to delay things. That's exactly the issue (note that the same thing applies at the country-level, but this is just exacerbated by the difference in wages from one country to another).

Working illegally could be as simple as not fulfilling residence permit/work permit conditions (usually they are restricted to a single employer or occupation), or using a work permit of country A on a different country B (with A and B in the Schengen Area), as people have said work visas and work permits are national permits. And illegal work is easier to detect.

@Dr.Snoopy I think it works like this, they get a work permit from country A and schengen visa, they go to country B with their schengen visa and apply for a job, the employer gets them a new workpermit. Not sure whats illegal about it, but I think end result is legal. Perhaps some steps inbetween are illegal.

@user1721135 If they have a work permit, that is usually in the form of a residence permit, they do not need a Schengen visa in that case at all, people cannot work in general with a Type-C Schengen visa, so are you sure the problem is the Schengen visa, or if they have a residence permit, they are allowed to move to other countries and apply for permits there. Still residence permits have limitations depending on the type, for example student permits usually allow you to work 20 hrs per week.

@Dr.Snoopy I am asking about both, short term passport sticker schengen visa - are you allowed to leave the country for other schengen country? Long term 3 year D visa, in the form of national ID card, are you allowed to go elsewhere? This is Bulgaria so not sure, we are kind of Schengen, but not on land apparently.

@user1721135 In general all Schengen visas, residence permits issued by Schengen states, allow you to move around the Schengen area, for different purposes and with limitations (like the 90/180 rule), but in general enforcing the limitations is difficult. People already answered here that there are Schengen visas valid for some countries only.

@user1721135 the german customs account posts regularly about illegal workers being found, with businesses and the workers charged as a result. Additionally, no visa national country can apply for a work-based residence permit inside Germany (only a few of the visa-free-countries can) when they have entered with a tourist visa. I'd say that your beliefs about undocumented work are not representative, especially of Germany.

This question may be more relevant on politics.SE?

Without dwelling on the specifics of different types of visas and work permits, the problem is basically this:

For enterpreneurs working in the tourism industry it is a very confusing situation, because their guest workers get issued schengen visas, but if the worker uses the schengen visa to go to another country the company may get investigated for human trafficking, according to politicians I spoke to.

Another way of dealing with this would be for the law to recognize that after facilitating the entry of a foreign short-term worker, a business has limited control over the worker's subsequent actions, and therefore hold the workers themselves primarily liable.  If your country's law's don't take this approach, you should talk to a local employment and/or immigration lawyer.  We can't help you understand what your country's laws say on the matter because you haven't told us what country it is.  I'm unaware of any EU legislation that would touch on this, but then again I wouldn't necessarily be, so it's possible that there is something.  Regardless, you need to find an answer in the context of your country's national law.

can a member state issue a non schengen visa or apply limitations to a schengen visa?

Provisions exist for this sort of thing, but they're supposed to be used only in exceptional cases, mostly when a person should normally not get a visa (for example because they overstayed in one country which issued a ban) but there's a country that wants to be able to let them visit anyway.  The point of this is to allow individual Schengen countries to admit the people that they want to admit.

But I wonder if there is any legal basis to prevent them from travelling with their schengen visas and why this responsibility is on the hotel and not on the government which gave them a schengen visa, they ultimately don't want them to use.

That's a question, as mentioned, for the lawyers and politicians of your country.  Certainly, a hotel can't arrest people as a government can, so the possibility of forcing them to do anything is limited.  Furthermore, someone with a Schengen visa is supposed to be able to visit other Schengen countries; if they work illegally there, they're violating the law of that country, not of yours, so it's unclear why your government should be involved at all, much less why they should impose any liability on the (former) employer who sponsored the initial visa.
It's possible that the politicians you spoke to were overstating the likelihood of investigation to deter you.  For example, it's possible that there's a crime related to fraudulently sponsoring people for work visas and that the facts you describe don't actually constitute this crime, but that an investigator might well look into the case so as to establish that you didn't do anything fraudulent.  To know for sure, you should obtain local legal advice.

The whole principle of the Schengen Area is that there aren't supposed to be any systematic border checks between Schengen countries (even though they are regularly re-introduced on some borders, especially recently).
So while it's actually possible to issue some types of visas with limitations on which countries it's valid for, there's no realistic way to enforce that. Unless one stumbles on a control (at the border or elsewhere), nobody will notice the restriction.
That's the reason Schengen Area countries don't like other member countries to give away visas (or residence permits, or even passports) too easily. The single travel area can only work if the rules are consistent.
Note however that getting a visa from one Schengen country, while it generally allows travel to other Schengen countries, does not allow work in other Schengen countries:

Type C visas do not allow work without an additional work permit, which is country-specific
Type D (national) visas allow work only in the country which issued it.

So they may go to another country and apply for jobs there, but they usually can't be hired by employers in that country without additional paperwork.
The issue is not that they travel to other countries (they are perfectly allowed to do so), it is that they do one of:

They work illegally in another country
They don't work but perform other illegal activities
They overstay
Or probably a combination.

In short: they get a way into Schengen through a "weak spot" (a country which gives visas and/or work permits more easily), and they stay and work illegally, probably in another "richer" Schengen country which would not have let them in in the first place.

It is very rare, but visas can be issued with restrictions, it would say for instance Etats Schengen (-DE) for a visa issued by France which does not allow travel to Germany. But again: the chance one gets checked is quite low.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The whole point of the system is that Schengen countries trust each other to apply the rules of the Schengen system and agreed to honor each other's visas. All short-stay visas are supposed to be Schengen visas, explicitly allowing travel between Schengen countries and exceptions (like short national visas or limited territorial validity visas) are supposed to be rare edge cases. It cannot really work any other way, the only alternative is between this and returning to national visas. This means that countries are not free to ignore or arbitrarily restrict a Schengen visa.
Another tenet of the system is that there should be no systematic checks at internal borders. That's a distinct issue but also essential to the Schengen system. Otherwise, you loose most of the practical benefits of the system (smoother travel, less enforcement costs) especially for EU citizens and residents (as they need to pay for the infrastructure and queue and stop as well). In practice, however, these rules on enforcement are increasingly being ignored by member states.
There is a long discussion in the comments about the issues you raise, what may or may not be illegal in this scenario, and whether that's actually a big problem but either way large-scale restrictions on Schengen  visas' territorial validity or any attempt to enforce that systematically would effectively destroy the architecture of the Schengen system so the answer to your question is that it is generally not possible under current Schengen rules.

So what justification is used to turn away a seasonal worker from Bulgaria, who boarded a plane to Vienna?

@user1721135 You don't need a justification because the action itself is clearly illegal. To the extent that there is any problem with that person, what Austria could or should do is detain them, invalidate their visa, and initiate any proceeding they think is necessary, including a removal, ban, etc. Simply “bouncing” them at the land border or turning them away at an airport is a lazy “solution” Schengen countries frequently abuse that's simply not foreseen by the Schengen rules. And if you violate the rules already, who cares about justification?

how can it be illegal when their visas say SCHENGEN STATES, which according to documentation means they are free to visit any Schengen country? Bulgaria is now in Schengen and issues full schengen visas, without restrictions. They could issue a restricted visa, for example disallowing Austria specifically but they don't.
I think these people get turned away on the Bulgarian airport already, they don't even reach Austria. But what is the justification?

@user1721135 What's illegal in my view is (1) systematic checks and (2) arbitrarily “bouncing” people at the border (instead of seeking readmission to another country under the Dublin system or initiating proceedings to force them to leave the entire area). It is not illegal for these people to go to Austria.
